# IEC connector with both Line and Neutral Fused

Tags: connector, mains, fuses

I require an IEC connector mains entry with both the Line and Neutral fused. The double fuse is required in order to be compatible with reverse polarity of the mains connector on the other side of the cable.

I tried googling or using a "farnell" (distributor) list:
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2328240.pdf
But to no avail. I may be blind to the exact data I am trying to find.

Maybe you can help out or have something else in mind that does the job.

Comment: Go to schurter.com and use their 2 pole fuse filter in the catalog. Eg: DD11.0121.1110

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but the comment brought me to a solution and the specific component I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer my own question:

If you are looking for a double fused IEC mains entry connector search for 2-pole fused or Twin-fused.

I found my component which is the next one:
PF0033/15/63 -  Power Entry Connector, Plug, 250 VAC, 10 A, Panel Mount, Quick Connect

Sometimes a different component may lead to the component you are searching for.

Good luck

Comment: It would be helpful to add that the component is manufactured by Bulgin.

Comment: You'd think? Based on my recent googling experiences with the search term "PF0033/15/63" the only thing I found was a Bulgin connector. I think this component number will suffice. Yahoo, duckduckgo, bing and ecosia agree with google.

Comment: Not sure if you are still  monitoring here, @Weaverworm but maybe you could accept your answer to your question to kind of help close it out?